# Decode UTF8 symbols

Tags: string, swift2, utf8-decode

I have a string in swift:

`let flag = "CattÃ¬ Ã²"`

I am trying to convert the `UTF8` symbols.

I have tried using

`stringByRemovingPercentEncoding`

but noting changes. How can I convert the symbols properly ?

Comment: What are you trying to convert to? Do you want the ascii code for the characters?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get as result `Cattà è`

Comment: Still a bit unclear. How did you get the original string in the first place? If you just want to get certain strings in an absolute way, reference this: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: I got the string from a json File

Comment: Did you decode a JSON *string* instead of JSON *data* by any chance? In this case, check the encoding used. It may be NSASCIIStringEncoding or another one that has to be used instead of NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the encoding guessing game! Look like somewhere along the pathway, your string didn't get the correct code page. Here's one way to guess it:

```
let flag = "CattÃ¬ Ã²"

let encodings = [NSASCIIStringEncoding,
    NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding,
    NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding,
    NSUTF8StringEncoding,
    NSISOLatin1StringEncoding,
    NSSymbolStringEncoding,
    NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding,
    NSShiftJISStringEncoding,
    NSISOLatin2StringEncoding,
    NSUnicodeStringEncoding,
    NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding,
    NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding,
    NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding,
    NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding,
    NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding,
    NSISO2022JPStringEncoding,
    NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding,
    NSUTF16StringEncoding,
    NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding,
    NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding,
    NSUTF32StringEncoding,
    NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding,
    NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding]

for encoding in encodings {
    if let bytes = flag.cStringUsingEncoding(encoding),
        flag_utf8 = String(CString: bytes, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        print("\(encoding): \(flag_utf8)")
    }
}
```

The array contains all the [encodings that Cocoa supports](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/String_Encodings).

From the results, it seems like your string was encoded in `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` (a.k.a ISO-8859-1), the default encoding for HTML 4.01. This gives `Cattì ò` in UTF-8, not exactly match your desired result but is the closest among all code pages.

Other good candidates are `NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding` and `NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding` so I'd suggest you check with other strings.